# Lookup Values in Pandas - 2 search Key

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have 2 tables from google sheets. df1 where it has the users completion of different modules. And df2 that consists of user details.

df1:

[image: df1]

df2:

[image: df2]

I want to merge tables just like the image below. Currently, I am able to achieve this using array vlookup. Sometimes I also use index match. But it takes forever because in reality, df1 has atleast 50000 rows, that is 40 modules for roughly 5000 users. I am new to python and pandas.

output:

[image: Completion tbl]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please update your question with **reproducible data, as text, not images**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot` to reshape df1, then `merge`:

```
df2.merge(df1.pivot(index='User Id', columns='Module', values='Status'), on='User Id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) do to:

```
# sample data 
df1=pd.DataFrame({'UserId': [1,1,2,2],
               'Module': ['Lesson1', 'Lesson2', 'Lesson1', 'Lesson2'],
               'Status': ['Completed', 'InProgress', 'Completed', 'Completed']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'UserId': [1,2],
                  'Name': ['John Smith', 'Jane']})

# merge and use unstack to reshape the data
df1=df1.merge(df2, on='UserId', how='left')
df1 = df1.set_index(['UserId', 'Name', 'Module']).unstack().reset_index()
# fix column names
df1.columns = df1.columns.get_level_values(0).tolist()[:2] + df1.columns.get_level_values(1).tolist()[2:]

print(df1)

   UserId        Name    Lesson1     Lesson2
0       1  John Smith  Completed  InProgress
1       2        Jane  Completed   Completed
```

Comment: works like charm. What if I will add another column in df1 which is Completion Date?